# Vintage sci fi movie about a group of people

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

While searching for less known sci fi movies online I run into a movie, saw few screenshots but can't remember the name of the movie now. Here's what I know:

1. The movie was roughly called something like "The charm of Bourgeoise" or the "The wonderful world of Bourgeoise something".
2. I remember a scene where a group of people were siting by the table
   and then they found themselves on a theater stage, the curtain lifts up and they see an audience looking at them followed by a group of people storming the stage with guns.
3. The movie is in color.

   What is this movie called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Discreet_Charm_of_the_Bourgeoisie) by the director Luis Buñuel, who did a number of surrealist films of this kind--a trailer featuring the scene you're remembering in #2 can be seen [here](http://vimeo.com/15257143).